# Android app: How to display continuous RGBA byte[] frame to a Surface?

Tags: android

My native JNI function will convert then return continuously RGBA byte[] frame to application layer. Now i want to display/preview it to a SurfaceView or TexttureView of application.

I did try & research for some hours but still there's no solution/sample to do it. Is there anyone did have experience about this matter, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

After some days of trying, i could display the byte[] frame using ANativeWindow and OpenGL ES by C/C++ source code.